# No se pueden leer propiedades indefinidas en Javascript

Tags: javascript, objeto

Tengo este ejercicio:
// informacion facturas
/* las facturas tienen nombre de la empresa,direccion telefono, nif,
nombre cliente, direccion, tlf y cedula, elemento, descripcion precio, cantidad ,
importe total, tipo de iva , forma de pago

anadir metodo que calcule importe total y actualice valor del corresp. y otro metodo
que muestre por pantalla el importe total */

```
var facturitas = factura = {
    nombre: 'gordonas', 
    direccion: 'el hatillo', 
    telefono: 2129633629,
    nif: '12jd-3jKu',
    producto: 'dona',
    descripcion: 'dona rellena de chocolate mas chispitas de chocolate',
    precio: 1.23,
    cantidad: 2, 
    importeTotal: importeTotal() ,
    tipoIva: 1.21 ,
    formaPago: 'tarjeta'

}


function importeTotal(){
    var importeTotal = (facturitas.precio * 1) / facturitas.tipoIva
    importeTotal = facturitas.importeTotal
    
}

function mostrarImporteTotal(){
    return  `el importe total es: ${facturitas.importeTotal} `
}
mostrarImporteTotal()
```

cuando corro el codigo me sale el error de 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'precio'') en la linea var importeTotal = (facturitas.precio * 1) / facturitas.tipoIva y la verdad no se por que sera. Antes tenia el codigo sin asignarle la variable facturitas a el objeto factura y me salia igual sin embargo cuando ponia el mouse encima de las propiedades del objeto no me salia nada, salia any y ahora que le asigne esa variable si me sale, entonces estoy un poco confundida, si alguien pudiera ayudarme por favor

Comment: Tengo curiosidad en saber porqué o cuál es el proposito de hacer `facturitas = factura = {...}` ya que luego no veo que hagas uso de `factura`.

Answer (score 2):

Bueno el problema que yo veo es que estás entrando en una especie de redundancia cíclica, es decir, cuando defines `facturitas` dependes de la función `importeTotal()`, pero esta a su vez depende de `facturitas` (o sea, de sí mismo) y como el objeto `facturitas` "no ha terminado" de crearse entras en ese conflicto.

Lo que yo sugiero es que hagas algo más genérico, una función que acepte el objeto con la información y que agregue la información adicional.

```js
const facturitas = {
  nombre: 'gordonas',
  direccion: 'el hatillo',
  telefono: 2129633629,
  nif: '12jd-3jKu',
  producto: 'dona',
  descripcion: 'dona rellena de chocolate mas chispitas de chocolate',
  precio: 1.23,
  cantidad: 2,
  tipoIva: 1.21,
  formaPago: 'tarjeta'

}

function importeTotal(factura) {
  factura.importeTotal = (factura.precio * 1) / factura.tipoIva
}

function mostrarImporteTotal() {
  importeTotal(facturitas);
  return `el importe total es: ${facturitas.importeTotal}`;
}

console.log(mostrarImporteTotal());
```

De este modo no solo funcionará para `facturitas`, también podrías usarlo con otros objetos de tipo factura.

Ahora, lo que también podrías hacer (pues según yo es el objetivo del ejercicio) es definir el método dentro del objeto.

```js
const facturitas = {
  nombre: 'gordonas',
  direccion: 'el hatillo',
  telefono: 2129633629,
  nif: '12jd-3jKu',
  producto: 'dona',
  descripcion: 'dona rellena de chocolate mas chispitas de chocolate',
  precio: 1.23,
  cantidad: 2,
  tipoIva: 1.21,
  importeTotal: function() {
    return (this.precio * 1) / this.tipoIva;
  },
  formaPago: 'tarjeta'
}


console.log(`El importe total es: ${facturitas.importeTotal()}`);
```

Comment: Como nota adicional, creo deberías multiplicar por `cantidad` y no por `1`, pero eso no es parte  del problema descrito.

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvio, gracias por la explicacion ya que estuvo clara

Comment: @anonymuus_gp si esta respuesta ayudó a resolver el problema, no olvides marcarla como aceptada y votar positivo. De ese modo ayudarás a otros usuarios a identificar las respuestas más útiles y a mejorar la calidad del sitio. Lee [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](/help/someone-answers) en el centro de ayuda. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

La declaración del objeto, como ya te indicaron, es incorrecta, debería ser simplemente

`var facturitas = {...}`.

Luego, dentro de dicha declaración estas llamando a la función `importeTotal`, antes de que sea definida, lo cual es un problema.

Y si ya estuviera definida, también estaría mal porque dentro de ella le estás queriendo asignar un atributo a facturitas, objeto que aún no está declarado.

Te dejo una posible solución:

```
const facturaOriginal = {
    nombre: 'gordonas',
    direccion: 'el hatillo',
    telefono: 2129633629,
    nif: '12jd-3jKu',
    producto: 'dona',
    descripcion: 'dona rellena de chocolate mas chispitas de chocolate',
    precio: 1.23,
    cantidad: 2,
    tipoIva: 1.21,
    formaPago: 'tarjeta',
};

const obtenerFacturaProcesada = factura => ({
    ...factura,
    importeTotal: (factura.precio * 1) / factura.tipoIva,
});

const facturaProcesada = obtenerFacturaProcesada(facturaOriginal);

function mostrarImporteTotal(factura) {
    console.log(`el importe total es: ${factura.importeTotal}.`);
}

mostrarImporteTotal(facturaProcesada);
```

Lo que hice fue crear una función `obtenerFacturaProcesada`
, que recibe una factura, la procesa (calcula y agrega el atributo importeTotal), y devuelve dicha factura.

Luego cree una variable `facturaProcesada`, que hace uso de dicha función.

Comment: yo entiendo que este incorrecta pero fue la mejor para que cuando yo accediera a las propiedades del objeto desde las funciones apareciera las variables si no aparece como any cosa que es como si no leyera las propiedades del objeto

Answer (score 0):

El método `importeTotal` del objeto `facturitas`, esta declarado como un método externo, por lo que no tiene relación con el contexto de ejecución de `facturitas`:

```
importeTotal: importeTotal()
```

Una forma de solucionarlo, es usando `Dynamic context`, pasando el contexto de ejecución de `facturitas` al método externo `importeTotal` por medio del método `apply`:

```
calcularImporteTotal: function(){
       importeTotal.apply(this);
    },
```

Para que las propiedades del objeto sean mas descriptivas, se cambio el nombre del método `importeTotal` por `calcularImporteTotal`; también, se agrega una nueva propiedad al objeto `facturitas` llamada `importeTotal`, la cual se usará más adelante para modificar su valor por referencia:

```
importeTotal: 0
```

Luego, se invoca al método `mostrarImporteTotal`, que a su vez invoca al método `facturitas.calcularImporteTotal()`:

```
function mostrarImporteTotal(){
    facturitas.calcularImporteTotal()
    return  `el importe total es: ${facturitas.importeTotal} `
}
console.log(mostrarImporteTotal())
```

Entonces, el método `facturitas.calcularImporteTotal()` invoca al método externo `importeTotal`, pero esta vez ya con el contexto de ejecución del objeto `facturitas`:

```
function importeTotal(){
    //aqui se ve el contexto de ejeucion de facturitas
    console.log(this)
}
```

Nótese que se puede acceder a todas las propiedades del contexto de ejecución `facturitas` por medio de la palabra reservada `this`, por ejemplo `this.precio`, `this.tipoIva`:

```
var importeTotal = (this.precio * 1) / this.tipoIva
```

Además, se puede acceder a la propiedad `importeTotal` y cambiar su valor:

```
function importeTotal(){
        var importeTotal = (this.precio * 1) / this.tipoIva
        this.importeTotal = importeTotal 
}
```

Finalmente, se pide la propiedad `importeTotal` del objeto `facturitas`, esto mostrará el último valor asignado a dicha propiedad, el cual fue modificado en el método `importeTotal` por **referencia**:

```
function mostrarImporteTotal(){
    facturitas.calcularImporteTotal()
    //facturitas.importeTotal fue modificado por referencia
    return  `el importe total es: ${facturitas.importeTotal} `
}
```

---

Demo

```js
var facturitas = {
    nombre: 'gordonas', 
    direccion: 'el hatillo', 
    telefono: 2129633629,
    nif: '12jd-3jKu',
    producto: 'dona',
    descripcion: 'dona rellena de chocolate mas chispitas de chocolate',
    precio: 1.23,
    cantidad: 2, 
    calcularImporteTotal: function(){
       importeTotal.apply(this);
    },
    importeTotal: 0,
    tipoIva: 1.21 ,
    formaPago: 'tarjeta'

}

function importeTotal(){
    //console.log(this)
    var importeTotal = (this.precio * 1) / this.tipoIva
    this.importeTotal = importeTotal   
}

function mostrarImporteTotal(){
    facturitas.calcularImporteTotal()
    return  `el importe total es: ${facturitas.importeTotal} `
}
console.log(mostrarImporteTotal())
```

#### Notas de campo

- Como comento el colega @ricardo-dlc, otra opción sería mover la declaración de los métodos externos, dentro del objeto `facturitas`.
- El método externo se podría usar con otros objetos y diferentes contextos de ejecución con la ayuda de `apply`, dependiendo de los requerimientos.

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

[this keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

[apply method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)